# How can I learn to read?

Tags: dwarf-fortress, dwarf-fortress-adventure

I've invested several hours in a human adventurer and want to learn the secrets of life and death. Unfortunately, I failed to invest any skill points in `Reader` at character creation. Is there any way for me to attain literacy?

Comment: Stash the book somewhere for a new apprentice to find!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to become literate unless you have some skill in reading in the first place. I believe I read something to that effect in the Adventure Mode Quickstart on the DF wiki.

Edit: It may not have been in the wiki, as I can't find it there, but I remember reading it somewhere. It might have been on the forums.

Comment: That is correct. Always start with novice reader, people. Reading is the new swimming!